# font-face icon font cross-browser and mobile browser compatability

Tags: css, mobile, font-face

I am using CSS to supply vector icons in place of images on an analysis tool I am creating. This makes it load faster and the images scale cleaner. They work fine on chrome and firefox. However, they are not appearing on IE9 or older android phones (pre v4.0 I think).

I've copied the relevant CSS below. Should I add a parallel part of CSS where I specify the browser or screen size to accommodate these devices? Or is there something I can do within this CSS to fix a bug, or provide a fall-back image? At the moment, the browsers show nothing at all where the icons should be.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'unicorns';
    src: url('font/unicorns.eot');
    src: url('font/unicorns.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/unicorns.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/unicorns.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/unicorns.svg#unicorns') format('svg');
}


.icon:before {
    font-family: "unicorns", sans-serif !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    /*text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; not supported in all browsers
    The text-rendering property is an SVG property that is not defined in any CSS standard. However, Gecko and WebKit browsers let you apply this property to HTML and XML content on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.*/
}
.boy:before {content: "a";}
.girl:before {content: "b";}

.respect:before {content: "r";}
.freedom:before {content: "m";}
.fun:before {content: "p";}

.icon-green:before {color: #008000;}
.icon-yellow:before {color: #e9b800;}
.icon-red:before {color: #cc0000;}
.icon-pink:before {color: #ff99ff;}

.icon-10:before {font-size: 10px; margin-right: 2px;}
.icon-30:before {font-size: 30px; margin-right: 5px;}
.icon-60:before {font-size: 60px; margin-right: 5px;}
.icon-90:before {font-size: 96px; margin-right: 5px; line-height: 100px;}
```

Comment: UPDATE: I added #iefix to 'font/unicorns.eot?#iefix' as it is supposed to fix ie8 and below problems. But that doesn't explain why this doesn't appear at all on IE9.